# Lodash's _.debounce() not working in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am trying to run a method called `query()` when a component property called `q` in Vue.js is modified.

This fails because `this.query()` is undefined. `This` is referring to my component's instance but somehow does not contain the methods.

Here's the relevant code part where I'm trying to watch the component property `q` and run the `query()` function:

```
methods: {
  async query() {
    const url = `https://example.com`;
    const results = await axios({
      url,
      method: 'GET',
    });
    this.results = results.items;
  },
  debouncedQuery: _.debounce(() => { this.query(); }, 300),
},
watch: {
  q() {
    this.debouncedQuery();
  },
},
```

Error:

> TypeError: _this2.query is not a function

If I write the `debounce()` call as below, the `TypeError: expected a function` error appears even earlier, at the page load.

```
debouncedQuery: _.debounce(this.query, 300),
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The issue comes from the lexical scope of the arrow function you define within `_.debounce`. `this` is bound to the object you are defining it in, not the instantiated Vue instance.

If you switch out your arrow function for a regular function the scope is bound correctly:

```
methods: {
  // ...
  debouncedQuery: _.debounce(function () { this.query(); }, 300)
}
```

Comment: Damn it! Thanks. I was sure I tried that option too. It works

Comment: Works great but eslint complains in .vue files "no-invalid-this".

Comment: odd, using this exact syntax isn't firing `this.query()` for me

Comment: I needed to bind this at create for it to work, probably like @BuddyZ's issue. 

`data() { return { searchCustomersDebounced: null, },`
`created() { this.debouncedQuery = _.debounce( () => { this.query(); }, 1000 );},`

Answer (score 6):

We can do it by plain JS (ES6) with few lines of code:

```
function update() {

    if(typeof window.LIT !== 'undefined') {
        clearTimeout(window.LIT);
    }

    window.LIT = setTimeout(() => {
        // do something...
    }, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

As answered in another post [This is undefined in Vue, using debounce method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083244/this-is-undefined-in-vue-using-debounce-method/62083798#62083798) the best way to add debouncing IMO is to create the method normally in methods as eg:

```js
    setHover() {
      if (this.hoverStatus === 'entered') {
        this.hoverStatus = 'active'
      }
    },
```

But then replace it in your created block eg:

```
  created() {
    this.setHover = debounce(this.setHover, 250)
  },
```