# This is undefined in Vue, using debounce method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I know that using the arrow syntax for a method will cause 'this' to not be mapped to the Vue instance, however in my example I'm using lodash.debounce, and as far as I know I'm not using the arrow syntax here?

**Returns Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined**

```
methods: {
  onChange: debounce(function(el) {
    this.$emit('change', el.target.value)
  }, 1000)
}
```

**is there a syntax error in the way I'm writing this debounce function without arrow notation?**

Comment: @Estradiaz No, `bind` or `() => {}` should not be used here. Vue will automatically `bind` the methods of a component to `this` when the component is instantiated. Using `() => {}` here wouldn't work because there is no component instance to bind to when the function is created.

Comment: well it does bind this to debounce, can you clearify that debounce binds this also? else it is the callback that has no vue this binding

Comment: @Estradiaz The function passed to `debounce` must not be bound in this case. Lodash's debounce implementation will preserve the value of `this` at the time when the debounced function was last called. In any case, you would be binding the function too early - there is no Vue component instance that `this` would even refer to at the time when `debounce()` is called.

Comment: @DecadeMoon thx for clarifying - somehow I didnt read the text above "returns cannot..."

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be working. Can you provide some additional context?

A slight improvement: it's usually best to create the debounced function per instance rather than sharing one across all instances of that component.

```js
methods: {
  onChange(e) {
    this.$emit('change', e.target.value)
  }
},

created() {
  this.onChange = _.debounce(this.onChange, 1000)
}
```

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  
  data: {
    text: '',
  },
  
  created() {
    this.onClick = _.debounce(this.onClick, 1000)
  },
  
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      // this is not undefined here
      this.text += 'Debounced! ';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="onClick">Click Me</button>
  <p>{{ text }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didnt find a proper Vue debouncing example but this worked